# What event need to be called when creating customer from Admin in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am trying to trigger an event when customer is getting created from Admin similar to

> "customer_register_success"

for the frontend . If I use this

> "adminhtml_customer_save_after"

I suppose  , it will be called on creation and updating the customer.

> Is there any event which can be used for new customer registration
>   from admin ?

I will really appreciate any help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **customer_save_after** event.

**Config.xml**

```
<adminhtml>
<events>
<customer_save_after>
    <observers>
        <savecustomer>
            <type>model</type>
            <class>module/observer</class>
            <method>customerSaveAfter</method>
        </savecustomer>
    </observers>
</customer_save_after>
</events>
</adminhtml>
```

Observer.php

```
<?php 
public function customerSaveAfter($observer)
{ 
    $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer(); //customer detail
}
```

Comment: Will this event be called again if I modify the account from the admin ? My scenario is to call a third party api when creating the customer and it should not be called on update ..

Comment: You have 3 options.
**1).** Make changes in saveAction function accordingly in Mage_Adminhtml_CustomerController class

Comment: **2).** Make database table with 3 fieilds. auto_increment_id, customer_id, observer_calling_status.   And make entry on first time customer save

Comment: **3)** Add new customer attribute which will store observer_calling_status

Comment: Thanks for your response , I think I need to use the 3 approach .. that seems to be better in my case